# Modifying Firefox native JavaScript method

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Here's the native code:

http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/content/contentAreaUtils.js

As you might have guessed, this is the JavaScript code Firefox uses when using the browser's 'save as' feature.

Is it possible to modify this code to suit my purpose (for my extension) by overriding the function? If so, how?
Or should I just create a whole new function with different name based on the native code?

EDIT:
I've decided to make own function, since I just realized modifying the original makes it permanent.

Comment: Yes easily. Just say `gBrowser.function = function() { this.blah }`. Remember that `this` will refer to the `gBrowser` in that function and not your add-on. So its prefectly fine, just copy paste from mxr to your add-on. See here: [MDN :: Avoid eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Appendix_C:_Avoid_using_eval_in_Add-ons?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=XUL_School%2FAppendix_C%3A_Avoid_using_eval_in_Add-ons)

Comment: Where's the native code? I see 'This web page is not available'.

Comment: @MikeW You supposed to open it via Firefox. I've edited the link, now you can access it from any browser.

Comment: No. Never overwrite natives (unless you just want to hook into every call). Define your own custom function.